# I can't use sizeof(struct hsearch_data) from <search.h>

Tags: c, search, hashtable, sizeof

I'm working on an open-source project, and there is an hash_table
that I need to change for a more efficient hash_table, so, I'm trying
to use the header `<search.h>`;

The problem, is that I need to overwrite the functions that is already
being used all over the project ... but for that, I need to use sizeof(struct hsearch_data)
but it doesn't work.

Follow the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <search.h>
#include "hashtable.h"

#define MAX_ELEMENTS 100
#define ERROR 2
#define SUCCESS 0

hash_table *new_hash_table()
{
    hash_table *table = (hash_table *) malloc(sizeof(struct hsearch_data));
    *table = {0};   

    int status = hcreate_r(MAX_ELEMENTS, table);

    if (status == 0) {
            hdestroy_r(table);
            return NULL;
    }

    return table; 
}
```

PS: in the header file, there is a
    typedef struct hsearch_data hash_table;

I got the error message:

```
hashtable.c: In function ‘new_hash_table’:
hashtable.c:18: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct hsearch_data’ 
hashtable.c:19: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Which platform are you on?  I'm looking at a RHEL5 Linux machine, and its `<search.h>` defines '`struct hsearch_data`' when `__USE_GNU` is defined, which is, in turn, defined when `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined as you have it.  However, not all machines are Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the trouble is that the `<search.h>` header on your platform does not define the structure type.  As noted in a comment to the question, on a RHEL5 Linux machine, the  defines '`struct hsearch_data`' when `__USE_GNU` is defined, which is, in turn, defined when `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined as you have it. However, not all machines are Linux.  I note that [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/search.h.html) does define the `<search.h>` header, but does not specify the structure you are seeking to use.

You will need to track down where the project defines the structure, and decide how you can make that available to this code.  It may be simple - if the structure is safely segregated in a header which can be safely included.  It may be complex if the header that defines the structure also defines other things which you can't use.

Since you are trying to preserve the same interface as the original code, you should be aiming to use the original header to provide the correct interface definition.

Answer (score 5):

Even though I still have some trouble with `hash_table`, I solved this specific problem:

it's something silly ... the

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

must be the first thing in the file ... I'm not sure about why you have to do that ... but it works.

Some people said something about `__USE_GNU`, this flag is set automatically when you use `#define _GNU_SOURCE`

And I changed the `malloc` to `calloc`, it was a good idea!

Comment: Could you please post some code snippets that helped you solve using `sizeof(struct hsearch_data)`?

Comment: +1 Thank you. I see the same thing: when I move "#define _GNU_SOURCE 1" to the very first non-comment line of the file, gcc now compiles it without complaint. I used to have the "#include <stdio.h>" line as the *only* line before the "#define _GNU_SOURCE 1" line, and at that time gcc threw a bunch of "incomplete type" error messages.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, you're not supposed to use `hsearch_data` yourself, but pointers to `hsearch_data` objects. Consequently, the header `search.h` would not expose its definition, merely a forward declaration. You are then not able to find its size.

If true, the library is designed for you to use the functions it provides, rather than rolling your own by stealing its datatypes.

Answer (score 2):

The reentrant versions with `_r` are GNU extensions to the hash functions in "search.h". If you look into the include file you'd see that they are protected by a macro name  `__USE_GNU` that doesn't seem to be documented, but that you probably have to set to use them properly. In particular your `sizeof` should then work.

*But*:

- your `malloc` should not be casted.
  In C you don't do that, `void*` can
  be assigned to any pointer to object.
- the line following your `malloc` will
  not work as you wrote it. This is
  initializer syntax and not for
  assignment.
- what they mean by zeroing out the initial table for `hcreate_r` is probable to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`
- if you want to do an "absolutely safe" initialization that *and* have a C99 conforming compiler (e.g gcc or clang) you could do the following assignment with a compound literal
  `*table = (struct hsearch_data){0};`